# How to stop python Regular Expression being too greedy

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match (in Python) the show name and season/episode numbers from tv episode filenames in the format:

`Show.One.S01E05.720p.HDTV.x264-CTU.mkv`

and

`Show.Two.S08E02.HDTV.XviD-LOL.avi`

My regular expression:

`(?P<show>[\w\s.,_-]+)\.[Ss]?(?P<season>[\d]{1,2})[XxEe]?(?P<episode>[\d]{2})`

matches correctly on Show Two giving me `Show Two`, `08` and `02`. However the 720 in Show One means I get back `7` and `20` for season/episode.

If I remove the `?` after `[XxEe]` then it matches both types but I want that range to be optional for filenames where the episode identifier isn't included.

I've tried using `??` to stop the `[XxEe]` match being greedy as listed in the python docs [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) module section but this has no effect.

How can I capture the series name section and the season/episode section while ignoring the rest of the string?

Comment: You might do better to do `name.split('.')`, then separate it by working backward from the end.

Comment: I originally used `split()` but I can't guarantee the files will be `.` delimited and number of items before the season/episode numbers would be variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the greedity on first match:

```
 p=re.compile('(?P<show>[\w\s.,_-]+?)\.[Ss]?(?P<season>[\d]{1,2})[XxEe]?(?P<episode>[\d]{2})')
 print p.findall("Game.of.Thrones.S01E05.720p.HDTV.x264-CTU.mkv")
 [('Game.of.Thrones', '01', '05')]
 print p.findall("Entourage.S08E02.HDTV.XviD-LOL.avi")
 [('Entourage', '08', '02')]
```

Note the `?`  following `+` in first group.

Explanation :

First match eats too much, so reducing its greedity makes the following match sooner. (not a really nice example by the way, I would have changed names as they definitely sound a bit too Warezzz-y to be honest ;-) )

Comment: Ah yes, that's a fair point, wasn't really thinking about that! Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: While this will bring you on the right track you should note that it will fail on edge cases where the name contains a 3-4 digit number (e.g. Some.Show.2011.S01E05.Some.Title.HDTV.XviD) since you make both Ss and EeXx optional. You will need to break these into two different statements seperated by a | in order to avoid that.

Comment: Correction to my statement above, just remove the optionality from [EeXx]: (?P<show>[\w\s.,_-]+?)\.[Ss]?(?P<season>[\d]{1,2})[EeXx](?P<episode>[\d]{2})\.

Comment: @Till +1; regexes are powerful, but they are not AI-complete.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
                    v
(?P<show>[\w\s.,_-]+?)\.[Ss]?(?P<season>[\d]{1,2})[XxEe]?(?P<episode>[\d]{2})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a dot at the end of the regex :

```
(?P<show>[\w\s.,_-]+)\.[Ss]?(?P<season>[\d]{1,2})[XxEe]?(?P<episode>[\d]{2})\.
                                                                      here __^
```